# How to quote a book in my novel?

Tags: novel, copyright, citations, legal

I write as a hobby and so my works are pretty amateur, but I still try to keep my writing as legitimate and proper as I can. My novel is about how a teenage boy (who is notorious for being a bad decision maker) makes a few bad decisions and has to start living and dealing with the consequences.

Throughout, he's been reading Oscar Wilde's novel, *The Picture of Dorian Gray*. There are a few instances where my character quotes the book, or where the narrator quotes the book, and the themes of morality resemble each other—in a roundabout way. I would compare it to how *She's the Man* is a modernized version of Shakespeares *Twelfth Night*.

My question is: Is it fine for me to use these quotes and make these comparisons? I understand Wilde has been dead for some time now, and that his works fall under public domain, I just don't want to misuse anything.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Dani*! A little tip about markdown: you need to have two spaces at the end of a line before hitting Enter to get a soft linebreak. Hitting Enter twice gives a paragraph. Most of the time I've seen people prefer paragraphs in their writing. There is a little box at the top of where you type your posts that can help you with the different markdown features and you can check the result below the box. You can also "suggest an edit" to others posts to check their markdown. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Another tip: it's recommended to wait a little (~24 hours) to let other users chime in. Your question hasn't been up for twenty minutes and there are users all around the globe in different timezones. You can always accept/unaccept as often as you like, but some people might be discouragred from interacting with your question when they think you have found your solution, so waiting can *potentially* increase the amount and quality of the answers you receive. Just at tip for the future: it's completely up to you to decide whether or not you want to accept something and if so what and when.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oscar Wilde's work is in the public domain; so yes, you can copy and quote it directly, even without attribution. You are doing Wilde a favor by attributing the quotes to his book. It isn't a problem.

Comment: This is a good answer for this specific situation, Amadeus, however could you possibly elaborate on the answer to apply it to quoting other novels in general beyond just Oscar Wilde?

Comment: @WhiteEagle I have taken the liberty to add a more general answer to Amadeus' specific one.

Answer (score 5):

You can look at this question from two levels: *legal* and *writing*.

#### Writing

From a writing perspective, in fiction there are no rules about how you have to cite other works.

If you write an academic journal article, you will have to follow a style guide on how to denote citations (e.g. put cited text in quotations marks) and in what format the source has to be given. In fiction, there are no such rules. You can do this however you want. If you like, you can write your whole novel in sentences cited from other works without acknowledging this even once.

In fiction you show how people behave in (something like) real life, and therefore citations in fiction are handled like citations in life. If you sing a song in real life, you don't usually add that this was a citation from a song and say who composed it. You just sing it, and others will recognize it or not, and if they don't and want to know the title, they ask. Do the same in fiction. If you have a character singing a verse from a song, then only mention the title of the song or the original singer or composer, *if the characters talk about this*. If they don't, don't mention it (in text) either. You can, if you want to, explain all your sources in an appendix, but (from the perspective of writing a story) you don't have to.

#### Legal

Legally, you may be required to acknowledge your use of copyrighted material and even ask for permission.<sup>1</sup> Usually, if the citations are brief and fall under [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use), you don't have to ask for permission, but it is still good practice to list the works and their respective copyright holders on your book's copyright page.<sup>2</sup>

If the works you cite from have been released into the public domain or if the copyright has expired, you can do what you want with the text. Other licenses, such as Creative Commons or GPL, will explain what you need to do.

---

<sup>1</sup> The legal situation may be different in different countries.

<sup>2</sup> We are not lawyers on this site. You may want to consult a lawyer when you are unsure about legal issues. As @celtschk has pointed out in a comment below, [be especially careful if you want to cite song lyrics or poems.](https://www.google.com/search?q=can%20I%20cite%20song%20lyrics%20in%20a%20novel)

Comment: Actually some time ago I came across [this](http://www.mlbanner.com/using-lyrics-in-your-book-could-be-expensive/) which, while actually about song lyrics, might also be relevant here.